# Plotting Log Likelihood

Tags: python, likelihood, gradient-descent

It was suggested I ask this here instead of Stack Overflow.

I am trying to plot the negative log likelihood of an exponential distribution. I am not getting how I am supposed to think of it. The equation for negative log likelihood is provided...

$$l(\lambda; x_1, \dots, x_n) = n \ln(\lambda) - \lambda \sum_{j=1}^n x_j$$

I am not getting how I am supposed to plot it when there is only one output. How is this used in relation to gradient descent? Is this function performed multiple times and the rate parameter changes? I have looked online and cannot find anything I can really understand.

Comment: The data $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ are treated as known constants.  These values never change for the given model.  The parameter $\lambda$ is the primary argument of the function.  For this model $\lambda>0$, hence you just need to code a function that takes two arguments $\lambda$, which changes, and $x_1, \cdots, x_n$, which are held fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have some numpy vector, x. Take the sum.

```
S = np.sum(x)
```

You have the sample size, n, by taking the length of x.

```
n = len(x) # maybe something related to x.shape
```

Now evelyate the function over a spectrum of lambda values, such as every $0.1$ from $-5$ to $+5$. I’ll call the variable “lamb” since “lambda” has a meaning in Python.

```
lamb = np.arange(-5, 5.01, 0.1)
L = n * np.log(lamb) - lamb * S
```

Plot it!

```
plt.scatter(x, L)
```

The likelihood function is just a function of your lambda values.

To find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\lambda$, determine the $\lambda$ that maximizes this function.

**SPOILERS BELOW**

(Don’t read ahead until you’ve figured out the bug in the above code (or at least have given it an attempt and think you’ve figured it out).)

You can’t take a logarithm of a number unless they it positive, so you would have to define your lamb vector as:

```
lamb = np.arange(0.1, 5.01, 0.1)
```

(Yes, [complex logarithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2089690/672549) exist.)

Comment: There’s a subtle bug in the code that will keep it from compiling. This was $100\%$ accidental, but im

Comment: Thank your for the help! This helped, but when it comes to the gradient descent part, please tell me if my understanding is correct: I want to take the derivative of the function. Then, either increase/decrease the lambda (from the func) to decrease the slope of the tangent line? When it's 0 I've arrived at my MLE?

Comment: Yes, the slope tells you the direction to move to get higher. If the slope is positive, move to the right. If the slope is negative, move to the left.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Mind helping with the derivative? When I look it up it seems that the derivative is (1/lambda) + (1/(lamdba^2))*(Sum of rand var X's). Is this incorrect? Should I just use a specific function?

Comment: If $f(x)=a\log(x)-bx$, what is $\frac{df(x)}{dx}?$

Comment: a/x - b? It's been a while. Where did the sum of all X's go? Are considering it a constant b?

Comment: The sum is a constant. You can plot your function in three dimensions to see how the sum changes the likelihood (perhaps a worthwhile exercise for both coding and statistics), but for any given data set, the sum is a fixed value (a constant).